# Echoing a variable in php gives one number and setting the variable to a cookie and evaluating the cookie gives another?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cookies

I have a variable in a post array called childnumber, which was a javascript variable sent to the server via an ajax post. In the php script it is here:

```
$newValue = $_POST["childnumber"]+1;
```

I have added 1 to it. Echoing $newvalue in the php script and sending it back to the client via the ajax response gives the correct number on the clientside html. But if I set the cookie

```
setcookie($cookieName,$newValue);
```

in the php instead of echoing it back to the client and check the cookies clientside the cookiename is correct but the new value comes out as just '1' everytime. So how do I get the cookie value to be the value which is echoed back to the client?

Thanks

Comment: How do you check the value in the cookie?

Comment: I check clientside manually using firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your process, you send an asynchronous request, process it by setting a cookie and... what do you send back?

I might be wrong (and be glad for any clarification from others) but does not the cookies are set along the http headers and therefore are accessible after you "reload" or redirect to new/same page?

Comment: That's right the cookie gets set and the next time the user reloads the page client side the cookie is accessible. If I check the cookie manually using firefox I can see it's value gets set to '1' everytime. But when I echo the variable to the client it's not 1.

Comment: To clarify nothing gets sent back when I set the cookie. But I tested echoing the post variable and it gives a different number back to the value in the cookie.

Comment: I have found a forum thread which says, that if you set cookie via ajax request, you must specify PATH and EXPIRES part of the cookie. See [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/php-34/setcookie-inside-ajax-request-627717.html)

Comment: Hello. I have specified the path and expires part of the cookie and still not luck. The cookie value is still set as '1' everytime, different to the value when I echo it.

Comment: Hmm well I've been fiddling around with things and it's started working. I basically deleted all the code and wrote it again and now it works (without specifying path and expires which is weird). I must have had a mistake somewhere.